# Is there an implementation of JointStateInterface, EffortJointInterface, PositionJointInterface and VelocityJointInterface in ros2?

Tags: ros, ros2, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. So, I have folloing lines of code in my ros1 project

---

```
hardware_interface::JointStateInterface js_interface_;
hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface ej_interface_;
hardware_interface::PositionJointInterface pj_interface_;
hardware_interface::VelocityJointInterface vj_interface_;
```

---

I have a problem with understanding, how this lines should look in ros2 Foxy. I'll appreciate any help. As far as I know EffortJointInterface  can be used in Galactic and all newer version, but I could be wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407866/is-there-an-implementation-of-jointstateinterface,-effortjointinterface,-positionjointinterface-and-velocityjointinterface-in-ros2?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may start with  https://control.ros.org/master/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html
And https://control.ros.org/master/doc/differences_to_ros1/differences_to_ros1.html

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2022-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-14**:
Thank you for reply. I read those two yesterday, and maybe I miss something, but there are no answer for this particular question in there. All that I get is assumption, that JointTrajectoryController is doing something similar to JointStateInterface, but still, maybe I am wrong here

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2022-10-14**:
As here written [github](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/61)

```
ros_control's JointStateInterface, EffortJointInterface, 
PositionJointInterface, VelocityJointInterface, *InterfaceProvider 
functionalities have been replaced by RobotHardware.
```

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-16**:
Oh, I see. Thank you for your help. You already answered my question, but still do you happen to know where to look this RobotHardware? I't is a little strange for me, but there are no RobotHardware in hardware_interface or joint_limits_interface.

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2022-10-16**:
You may find something here: [demo hardware](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/tree/master/ros2_control_demo_hardware)

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-16**:
I couldn't find any RobotHardware uses there. Still, thank you for your help.